# Unable to enter any data in Google page through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to open a google page, but I am unable to enter any text in the Search bar. My execution stops only after opening the Google page.

Below is the code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FirePath {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Driver.get("http://www.google.com");
//Driver.wait(50);
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']']")).sendKeys("some text");
//Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gb_P")).click();
//Driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/a[1]")).click();
}

}
```

Comment: use `lst-ib` as id

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, if you want to enter text in Search input field:

```
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("some text");
```

or

```
Driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for this.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Some Text");
driver.findElement(By.id("_fZl")).click();
```